Using Controls that are time-invariant with the difference-in-differences estimators
I ran an experiment in which there was 2 groups of participants performing the exact same task during a first period. In the second period, the two groups had to perform the same task a second time. However, for one group I introduced an additional information for the second part. The two groups are called Social Information condition, and No Social Information condition.
The model put in its simplest form is the following:
DE=Beta0 + Beta1 X SocialInfo + Beta2 X Time +Beta3 X SocialInfo X Time + u
(Sorry for not putting the indexes).
DE is the dependant variable i.e. the disposition effect.
Social Info is a dummy variable taking 0 when there is no Social Info (no treatment), 1 when there is the treatment Social Info.
Time is a dummy variable taking 0 for the first part of the study, 1 for the second part.
From here, everything seems fine to me in terms of understanding BUT here's where I think I might have made a mistake:
In each group, participants had different time constraint to carry out the task in the 2 periods: No time constraint, 20s time constraint, 10s time constraint. The model I did was thus the following:
DE=Beta0 + Beta1 X SocialInfo + Beta2 X Time +Beta3 X SocialInfo X Time + Beta4 X 20TC + Beta5 X 10TC + Beta6 X Demographic controls+ u
10TC and 20TC are dummy variables that take 1 if the individual had a 10s or 20s to make the task in each period, 0 if he had no time constraint.
To me, those coefficients represented baseline differences that is the difference between those who have no social info and no time constraint and those with no social info but a time constraint.
Demographic controls represent variables that were measured prior doing any task such as Risk Aversion, Loss Aversion, Gender, Age, ect... for instance.
I thought adding those will allow me that have more precise estimates.
But as I have no material to verify this, I am doubting a lot if adding them was a wise thing to do.
I took the risk because the DiD estimator (Beta3) did not change by adding those variables.
My questions are the following:
Why does the coefficient of the did estimator remained the same with or without those controls (that do not vary with time)?
And why adding controls that are time invariant in a mistake in a regression model that uses the DiD estimator?

Welcome. Can you tell us more about your treatment? I wonder whether you could use the time constraints as different types (levels) of exposure. Participants not only got more information, but also more time to complete the task.

The treatment called Social Info is the introduction of information regarding the actions taken by a performing trader that did the trading decision task in a pilot experiment.

The conditions with or without social information can be subdivided into 3 groups that have different times to make their decisions: no time constraint, 20s time constraint (20TC) and 10s time constraint (10TC)

Just so I understand you correctly, you plan to subdivide the "treated" group (social information condition) into three groups: no time constraint, 10 second time constraint, and 20 second time constraint? Is the "control" group (no social information condition) also subdivided into groups?
